# Instantly get values from Select Box

Tags: php, html-select

I have made a web page where a dropdown select box has 5 different membership types. All memberships have different prices (obviously).

Here is the code before i say anything more:

```
$form = new jqmForm('RegForm');
$form->method('post');
$membsel = $form->add(new jqmSelect('membership','membership','Select Membership:'), true);
$membsel->add(new jqmOption('Sailing Junior - under 19 years old on 12 October', 'sailJunior', false));
$membsel->add(new jqmOption('Junior Family Membership - See notes', 'juniorFamily', false));
$membsel->add(new jqmOption('Sailing Senior - over 19 years old on 12 October', 'sailSenior', false));
$membsel->add(new jqmOption('Senior Family Membership - See notes', 'seniorFamily', false));
$membsel->add(new jqmOption('Non Sailing Members - all ages', 'nonSailing', false));
if ($_POST['sailJunior']){
    $form->add(new jqmLabel('itemFee', '<h3 align=center>$100</h3>'));
}
else if ($_POST['juniorFamily']){
    $form->add(new jqmLabel('itemFee', '<h3 align=center>$185</h3>'));
}
else if ($_POST['sailSenior']){
    $form->add(new jqmLabel('itemFee', '<h3 align=center>$255</h3>'));
}
else if ($_POST['seniorFamily']){
    $form->add(new jqmLabel('itemFee', '<h3 align=center>$395</h3>'));
}
else if ($_POST['nonSailing']){
    $form->add(new jqmLabel('itemFee', '<h3 align=center>$20</h3>'));
}
$form->add(new jqmInput('quantity', 'quantity', 'integer', '', 'Quantity', 'c', true));
$form->add(new jqmLabel('totalFee', '<h3 align=center>0</h3>', ''));
$form->add(new jqmInput('submit', 'submit', 'submit', 'submit', '', 'b', true));
```

Now, what i want to do is get the Label to show the corresponding price instantly, without having to click on submit all the time. That means when i click an item in the select box, i want the label to produce the price of that item.

How would i go about doing this?
Any and all help would be great.
And to those of you who don't know why my code looks weird, it's because I am using jqmPhp.

Comment: You can accomplish you goal with JavaScript.

Comment: You cannot do this with PHP as it's server side and requires you to submit to it for processing. You need Javascript

Comment: Use Ajax and/or just JS with an event listener. Ajax is powerful stuff ;-)

Comment: Any tips on how the javascript/Ajax code would look like?

Comment: @AnujHari Here's one that seems promising http://click.avoka.com/click-examples/ajax/select/ajax-select.htm --- Plus you will get a lot of results if you Google "ajax listener" or "ajax listener mysqli form select"

Comment: @AnujHari A similar question just came up, have a look at the question and answers, hope this helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884713/dynamic-drop-down-list-using-html-and-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use PHP to do this, it's not designed to do what you're after, you can use AJAX to do requests in the background but you said you didn't want to have to click on submit all the time so that leaves JQuery or JavaScript. If you haven't used much JavaScript then I would advise against JQuery for the time being and learn the basics of JavaScript. You will be surprised how quickly you pick up JQuery and AJAX afterwards. A quick way of getting one value to another place on a page instantly with JavaScript would be using a sudo datalist and variables inside a loop in a function that you could call on an onChange event. Something like this:

```
<style>
#hidden {
    display:none;
}
</style>

<select onChange='price(this.options[this.selectedIndex].id)'>
    <option>Select an Option</option>
    <option id='optionId[1]' >Product 1</option>
    <option id='optionId[2]' >Product 2</option>
    <option id='optionId[3]' >Product 3</option>
    <option id='optionId[4]' >Product 4</option>
</select>
<div id='hidden'>
    <p id='hiddenId[1]'>100</p>
    <p id='hiddenId[2]'>200</p>
    <p id='hiddenId[3]'>300</p>
    <p id='hiddenId[4]'>400</p>
</div>
<p id='preview'></p>

function price(get_id) {
    i = 1;
    var priceValue = '';
    var optionId = new Array();
    var hiddenId = new Array();
    while (i <= 4) {
        optionId[i] = 'optionId['+i+']';
        hiddenId[i] = 'hiddenId['+i+']';
        if (get_id == optionId[i]) {
            priceValue = document.getElementById(hiddenId[i]).innerHTML;
            document.getElementById('preview').innerHTML = priceValue;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry. i thought it was working, but var priceValue = document.getElementById('hiddenPrice[i]').innerHTML; comes up with a parse error.

Comment: @AnujHari sorry, was tired last night. That should work now, make sure not to load it on page load or it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

you can find so many "chained select" examples

instead of populating it in another select you can do it in your way ..

http://tutorialzine.com/2011/11/chained-ajax-selects-jquery/

http://www.9lessons.info/2010/08/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using.html

Comment: I am so confused. I'm completely new to javascript/ajax.
Wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction.
I can't seem to find anything that fits my certain requirement.
I want to be able to click on a membership type which triggers a label to change values.