# How to show drop down list for a selected value?

Tags: html, forms, list

i have a drop down list in a html form. if the user selects any option in this, based on the selection i want to show another drop down list.

```
   <select name="places">
    <option value="-1">Select</option>
      <option value="nilgiris">Nilgiris </option>
      <option value="coimbatore">Coimbatore</option>
      <option value="chennai">Chennai</option>
    </select>
```

for example if the user selects 'Nilgiris' i want show places in Nilgirs like ooty, coonoor, kotagiri...

```
  <option value="ooty">Ooty </option>
  <option value="coonoor">Coonoor</option>
  <option value="kotagiri">Kotagiri</option>
```

How to do it...

```
function check(elem) {
    document.getElementById('places1').disabled = !elem.selectedIndex;
    }

<select name="places" onchange="check(this);">
        <option value="-1">Select</option>
          <option value="nilgiris">Nilgiris </option>
          <option value="coimbatore">Coimbatore</option>
          <option value="chennai">Chennai</option>
        </select>


<select id="places1" disabled="disabled" >
<option>Ooty</option>
<option>Coonoor</option>
<option>Kotagiri</option>
</select>
```

this code enables the 'places1' dropdown list on any selection in 'places' dropdown list...

i want to make it enable only for selecting Nilgiris in the 'places' drop down list.

how to make it???

Comment: Possible duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884713/dynamic-drop-down-list-using-html-and-php

Comment: You may use AJAX to get a Multiple Select Dropdown List

Answer (score 0):

for select tag there is 'onselect' event.
'onselect' Fires after some text has been selected in an element. You can call function onselect event.

You will get selected value into function depend upon that value you can bind second the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="places" id="dropdownlist" onchange="formulaTypeChange()">
  <option value="-1">Select</option>
  <option value="nilgiris">Nilgiris</option>
  <option value="coimbatore">Coimbatore</option>
  <option value="chennai">Chennai</option>
</select>
<select id="nilgiris" style="display:none">
  <option value="ooty">Ooty</option>
  <option value="coonoor">Coonoor</option>
  <option value="kotagiri">Kotagiri</option>
</select>
<select id="coimbatore" style="display:none">
  <option value="mtp">MTP</option>
  <option value="pollachi">Pollachi</option>
  <option value="CBE">CBE</option>
</select>
<select id="chennai" style="display:none">
  <option value="perambur">Perambur</option>
  <option value="guduvancheri">Guduvancheri</option>
  <option value="mahabalipuram">Mahabalipuram</option>
</select>
```

Four drop down list with the respective options.

```
function formulaTypeChange() {
     if($("#dropdownlist").find('option:selected').val()== "nilgiris"){
         $('#nilgiris').css('display', 'block');
         $('#coimbatore').css('display', 'none');
         $('#chennai').css('display', 'none');
     } else if (str == 'coimbatore') {
         $('#nilgiris').css('display', 'none');
         $('#coimbatore').css('display', 'block');
         $('#chennai').css('display', 'none');
     } else if (str == 'chennai') {
         $('#nilgiris').css('display', 'none');
         $('#coimbatore').css('display', 'none');
         $('#chennai').css('display', 'block');
     }
 }
```

Based on values in #dropdownlist the consequent drop down list appears. Hope this helped.