# PHP Dropdown List Causing Endless Loop

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo, while-loop

I am trying to dynamically populate a drop down list in PHP and it is causing an endless loop and my browser to crash.  I do not know how to correctly get it to show all the rows in one table but I would think this would be a relatively simple fix. The while loop might be throwing it off. Let me know if you need more information  I am following this example but mine is written in PDO:

[Dynamic drop down list using html and php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884713/dynamic-drop-down-list-using-html-and-php)

```
<h3>Company Listing</h3>
           <select name='companies'>
            <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
          <?php
          //gets user's info based off of a username.
    $query = "SELECT business_name FROM Businesses";

    try 
    {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);

    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
    }

//fetching all the rows from the query
$profileRow = $stmt->fetch();
while ($profileRow) 
{ 
?>

<option value="<?php echo $profileRow['business_name']?>"><?php echo $profileRow['business_name']?></option>

<?php
}
?>
    </select>
          <p></p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$profileRow` is not changing . so it will always be true

You need to do it like this

`while($profileRow = $stmt->fetch())`

Comment: That's it! Thanks! I will mark your answer as the correct one as soon as I can.

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
$profileRow = $stmt->fetch();
while ($profileRow) 
{
```

to

```
while ($profileRow = $stmt->fetch()) 
{
```

so that `$profilerow` keeps changing and eventually evaluates to something equivalent `FALSE` inside the `while` condition when there are no more rows left. In your version `$profilerow` becomes an object and never changes. An object evaluates to `TRUE` in the `while` condition.